# Chrome not setting cookie on AJAX POST

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, cookies

I do an AJAX POST to my webservice, and it sets 2 cookies in the response, but Chrome does not set them. Safari and Firefox do, however.

Here's the request:

```
POST /api/login HTTP/1.1
Host: 0.0.0.0:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 50
accept: application/json
Origin: http://0.0.0.0:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36
content-type: application/json
Referer: http://0.0.0.0:8080/form
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,nl;q=0.6,de;q=0.4,fr;q=0.2,pl;q=0.2
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Vary: X-HTTP-Method-Override, Accept-Encoding
x-frame-options: sameorigin
set-cookie: keystone.uid=s%3A55efe88923f753865f7a0985%3Ac5aT64aih9lxXi%2BNiSMr1rUJW4kzWyyNUforvUOrckk.JovuV%2FqeoQ32PiuyNPAZ7JcbIxXBcBvj%2FWFp8vf3SQQ; Path=/; HttpOnly
set-cookie: keystone.sid=s%3ADcv5el-TjLRkOSH9vNbvxQoOai-SQj-3.ZTfPFwEZp5mdVHSDZTukO%2FnrDnSpGU3OMW3tQu%2FSz7U; Path=/; HttpOnly
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 224
ETag: W/"e0-B6OeRPdDEP0WPVdlZHqarA"
Date: Fri, 06 Nov 2015 14:39:37 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

I'm out of ideas. This doesn't work with a fully qualified domain name on port 80 either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution:

You have send the request with credentials (`XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials` or e.g. `credentials: 'include'` for [whatwg fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch)).

<strike>Even though this is pointless since you're logging in and don't have any/have invalid cookies, it makes Chrome store the cookies from the returned answer. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯</strike>

As pointed out by @Anne, the `XMLHTTPRequest` specification actually requires user agents to disregard returned cookies unless `withCredentials` is specified. http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-withcredentials-attribute

Comment: It is not actually pointless. The credentials settings govern both outgoing and incoming credentials simultaneously.

Comment: So basically FF and Safari have buggy implementations?